# xenserver_don't found /etc/xend/xend-config.sxp file

Tags: xen

I am trying to create a bridge network. My problem is I can not find `/etc/xend/xend-config.sxp` file on my xenserver.

Can someone give me a hand? Someone knows where can I find xend-config.sxp file?

Note: I'm using Xenserver 6.5.

Answer (score -1):

Firstly I assume you have connected to your server through a terminal, likely using ssh.

1. Use the command `cd /etc/xend/` This will change the directory into this folder.
2. To see the contents of the folder type `ls`. If there is anything in the folder, such as the `xend-config.sxp` file it will show up.
3. If the file does not show up you can create it. It often seems to be the case that configuration files need to be created by one self the first time.
4. You can do this by running the command `touch xend-config.sxp`
5. Running the command `ls` should now show you the file. Running `pwd` will show you that it has been created at `/etc/xend/`
6. To edit the file you can use an editor such as nano or vim or whatever is your personal choice, e.g. `sudo nano xend-config.sxp` will open the file xend-config.sxp in a nano text editor.

I hope this helps